# Bug in recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, random

I'm trying to get a pin number with only 4 digits. But the numbers that are less than 1000 are also getting printed. What is happening in this code?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Util {

    public static int getRandomPINNumber(){
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomNo = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000);
        if(randomNo < 1000)
        getRandomPINNumber(); //repeat if it is less than 1000,some bug here
        return randomNo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0;i<100; i++)
            System.out.println(getRandomPINNumber());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
6413
1692
5734
105  <--- why 105 is getting printed, it should reevaluate the pin right? 
4857
6348
1355
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to do this recursively, instead of simply using a while-loop?

Comment: No, not at all. I will go with @Bathsheba 3 point in his answer. Got a cool tip

Comment: Isn't 0001 a valid PIN code ? :)

Comment: Yes.. You are right. But, I want to make it as simple as 1000 - 9999. I used the samething

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are not returning the result of the recursive call. Change you code to:

```
public static int getRandomPINNumber(){
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNo = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000);
    if(randomNo < 1000)
        return getRandomPINNumber(); //repeat if it is less than 1000
    return randomNo;
}
```

When you call the function for the first time and a number less than 1000 is generated, you recursively call `getRandomPINNumber` but ignore the return value.

Also, you should not call `new Random()` multiple times. Call it once and store the result.

Comment: You can remove "some bug here" :-)

Comment: Plus one for mentioning the multiple call of `Random()`. If I had a dollar for every occasion I've spotted that...

Comment: Thank you, I'm silly about this.. Thanks a lot.. I will make the creation of Random instance once..

Answer (score 3):

Three things, in order of increasing pedantry

1. You need to return the value of the recursive function: `return getRandomPINNumber();` else you're discarding the result.
2. Don't call `Random randomGenerator = new Random();` multiple times, else you ruin the statistical properties of the generator. Have `randomGenerator` as a field of your class, or pass it in to your function.
3. Never discard results of a random number generator else you will introduce some statistical bias. (Over the years very many research papers have been debunked due to improper random number generator usage). In your case you can use  `int randomNo = randomGenerator.nextInt(9000) + 1000;` and drop the discarding altogether.

Comment: Can you elaborate on/link to explanation on how regenerating all values under 1000 introduces statistical bias here?

Comment: Dig around by Googling "statistical bias in linear congruential generators". I think Numerical Recipes In C also has sections on it. In short, you'll increase your variance (and higher moments), which means your sample could well fail a chi-square test for uniformity.

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint, actually you don't need to use recursion here:

```
    return randomGenerator.nextInt(9000) + 1000;
```

is a much more simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the code you want to process after the if statement in curly braces and assign the result of the method to randomNo.

```
int randomNo = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000);
if (randomNo < 1000) {
    randomNo = getRandomPINNumber(); //repeat if it is less than 1000,some bug here
}
return randomNo;
```

You could also avoid values that are < 1000 by using

```
int randomNo = randomGenerator.nextInt(9000) + 1000;
```

This will return numbers from 1000 to 9999 and is a much cleaner solution than recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I made the code this way,

```
public class Util {

    static Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    public static int getRandomPINNumber(){
        int randomNo = randomGenerator.nextInt(9000) + 1000;
        return randomNo;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0;i<100; i++)
            System.out.println(getRandomPINNumber());
    }

}
```

Posting the fully bug free code following all the information / tips from other answers